# One line python code to remove all the strings that doesn't start with T or t and if they contain number greater then 6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop, filter

Eg:

```
List=["tata1","tata2","Tata3","mdkjd","djhdj","Tata8","t9","t2"]
```

Output should be:`["tata1","tata2","Tata3","t2"]`

I tried :

```
content = [item for item in List if terminal.lower().startswith('t')]
```

My doubt if I can append one more condition with the if I used in my code?

If yes, how?

I tried writing but it gives error.

Comment: use `and`, `or`  - ie. `if x and y or z:`

Comment: yes i included "and" after my first if condition but in order to check for number i need to traverse in each and every character of string,thats where its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `and` to test multiple conditions.

```
>>> [i for i in l if i and i[0] in 'tT' and all(j not in i for j in '789')]
['tata1', 'tata2', 'Tata3', 't2']
```

So from left to right this will test:

- non empty string
- starts with `'t`' or `'T'`
- has any of the digits `'7'`, `'8'`, or `'9'`

These conditions will "short circuit" meaning upon the first test failing, there is no need to check the following conditions as `False and (anything)` is always `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Matching your required output requires using `all` and `not in` to check that none of the `'789'` characters are contained in your input string while also checking for the starting characters:

```
res = [s for s in List if s[0] in ('tT') and all(j not in s for j in '789')]
```

Now `res` contains:

```
['tata1', 'tata2', 'Tata3', 't2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print filter(lambda x: re.match(r'^[Tt].*[0-6]',x),l)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.